# Is this correctly parsed?

Tags: compiler-construction, operator-precedence

Grammar: E -> E + E | E * E | (E) | id

Operator Precedences:

- (plus) has higher precedence than *
- (multiply) has higher precedence than `(` and `)`
- `(` and `)` have equal precedence

Input: id + id * id

[image]

I parsed it like this, not sure if it's correct.